# How to connect to SQL Server from .NET Core without using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

How can we connect to SQL Server from .NET Core **without** using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are surprised with `BaseDataAccess` class format in [BRAHIM Kamel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825757) and the article<sup>1</sup> they reference, here is essentially the same code but properly reformatted so that it's usable. Hopefully it will save you some time.

```
public class BaseDataAccess
{
    protected string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public BaseDataAccess()
    {
    }

    public BaseDataAccess(string connectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    private SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    protected DbCommand GetCommand(DbConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection as SqlConnection);
        command.CommandType = commandType;
        return command;
    }

    protected SqlParameter GetParameter(string parameter, object value)
    {
        SqlParameter parameterObject = new SqlParameter(parameter, value != null ? value : DBNull.Value);
        parameterObject.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        return parameterObject;
    }

    protected SqlParameter GetParameterOut(string parameter, SqlDbType type, object value = null, ParameterDirection parameterDirection = ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
    {
        SqlParameter parameterObject = new SqlParameter(parameter, type); ;

        if (type == SqlDbType.NVarChar || type == SqlDbType.VarChar || type == SqlDbType.NText || type == SqlDbType.Text)
        {
            parameterObject.Size = -1;
        }

        parameterObject.Direction = parameterDirection;

        if (value != null)
        {
            parameterObject.Value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            parameterObject.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        return parameterObject;
    }

    protected int ExecuteNonQuery(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        int returnValue = -1;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = this.GetConnection())
            {
                DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, commandType);

                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }

                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogException("Failed to ExecuteNonQuery for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
            throw;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    protected object ExecuteScalar(string procedureName, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        object returnValue = null;

        try
        {
            using (DbConnection connection = this.GetConnection())
            {
                DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }

                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogException("Failed to ExecuteScalar for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
            throw;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    protected DbDataReader GetDataReader(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        DbDataReader ds;

        try
        {
            DbConnection connection = this.GetConnection();
            {
                DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, commandType);
                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }

                ds = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogException("Failed to GetDataReader for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
            throw;
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

<sup>1: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35974.exploring-net-core-net-core-1-0-connecting-sql-server-database.aspx</sup>

Comment: I would suggest this is not "well formatted". Parameter collection is evaluated for null or empty in three different methods. It's a bit messy to have methods return DbConnection and DbParameter, then cast them back to SqlConnection when using the values. If this class operates on System.Data.SqlClient namespace objects, don't use the base type of those objects for method return types. Lastly, the DbConnection in GetDataReader is not disposed, which could be VERY problematic.

Comment: Please only add new content in answers. Repeating existing answers just with different formatting is... not a new answer. If you think the answer above is useful sans its bad formatting, just edit it to fix the formatting instead of posting a new answer.

Answer (score 30):

First, you have to add the NuGet package `System.Data.SqlClient`

```
 Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient
```

Then you can use the traditional way, which uses `SqlConnection`. Here is an example:

> ```
> public class BaseDataAccess
> {
>    protected string ConnectionString { get; set; }
>
>    public BaseDataAccess()
>    {
>    }
>
>    {
>    public BaseDataAccess(string connectionString)
>    private SqlConnection GetConnection()
>        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
>    }
>
>    {
>        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
>        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
>            connection.Open();
>        return connection;
>        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection as SqlConnection);
>    }
>
>    protected DbCommand GetCommand(DbConnection connection, string commandText, CommandType commandType)
>    {
>    protected SqlParameter GetParameter(string parameter, object value)
>        command.CommandType = commandType;
>        return command;
>    }
>
>    {
>        parameterObject.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
>        SqlParameter parameterObject = new SqlParameter(parameter, value != null ? value : DBNull.Value);
>        return parameterObject;
>    }
>
>        SqlParameter parameterObject = new SqlParameter(parameter, type); ;
>    protected SqlParameter GetParameterOut(string parameter, SqlDbType type, object value = null, ParameterDirection parameterDirection = ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
>    {
>
>        if (type == SqlDbType.NVarChar || type == SqlDbType.VarChar || type == SqlDbType.NText || type == SqlDbType.Text)
>        {
>    }
>            parameterObject.Size = -1;
>        }
>
>        parameterObject.Direction = parameterDirection;
>
>        if (value != null)
>        {
>            parameterObject.Value = value;
>        }
>    else
>    {
>        parameterObject.Value = DBNull.Value;
>    }
>
>    return parameterObject;
>
>    DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, commandType);
>    protected int ExecuteNonQuery(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
>    {
>        int returnValue = -1;
>
>        try
>        {
>            using (SqlConnection connection = this.GetConnection())
>            {
>
>                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
>                {
>                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
>                }
>
>            using (DbConnection connection = this.GetConnection())
>                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>            }
>        }
>        catch (Exception ex)
>        {
>            //LogException("Failed to ExecuteNonQuery for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
>            throw;
>        }
>
>        return returnValue;
>    }
>
>    protected object ExecuteScalar(string procedureName, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
>    {
>        object returnValue = null;
>
>        try
>        {
>            {
>        }
>                DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
>
>                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
>                {
>                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
>                }
>
>                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
>            }
>        }
>        catch (Exception ex)
>        {
>            //LogException("Failed to ExecuteScalar for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
>            throw;
>
>        return returnValue;
>    }
>
>     ds = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
>    protected DbDataReader GetDataReader(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
>    {
>        DbDataReader ds;
>
>        try
>        {
>            DbConnection connection = this.GetConnection();
>            {
>                DbCommand cmd = this.GetCommand(connection, procedureName, commandType);
>                if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
>                {
>                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
>                }
>
>            }
>        }
>        catch (Exception ex)
>        {
> }
>            //LogException("Failed to GetDataReader for " + procedureName, ex, parameters);
>            throw;
>        }
>
>        return ds;
>    }
> ```

Copied from  [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35974.exploring-net-core-net-core-1-0-connecting-sql-server-database.aspx).

> that is still confusing for me... .Net Core & .Net standard vs regular .Net: How do we know which packages we can use with .Net core?

Dependencies means that what you should have installed on your machine in order to use the package or NuGet will install it for you. To understand how dependencies work in .NET, take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution).

**Note** - if a package targets the .NET Standard library, it will probably  mostly work on both .NET core and the .NET Standard framework.

Comment: can you reference the standard .Net Framework classes from .Net Core? Does'nt that sort of defeat the point of .Net Core?

Comment: the referenced link points us to a Microsoft SQL Server Database Provider named "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"

Comment: you have to add the nuget package

Comment: yes but if it was just for illustration purpose you can achieve the same just by  adding the package because it's compatible  with .net standard which is compatible  with .net core

Comment: Thanks, that's the bit that is still confusing for me... .Net Core & .Net standard vs regular .Net: How do we know which packages we can use with .Net core? http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/ does not state it clearly, and the dependency list even complicates it more

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted as an answer!!!??? This uses EFCore! From the TechNet link: "Add a Reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer using one of following methods:" @BRAHIM mentions this using nuget.

Comment: @BrettSpencer just note when you install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` the  `System.Data.SqlClient`  is installed by default because it depends on so may  be the author of the article has a reason for doing this but I'm sure 100 % that if you install  only `System.Data.SqlClient  ` the code in the pointed article still valid

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Thank you, I just installed only System.Data.SQLClient via pmc and can confirm that, indeed, it does work without EF. Nice! This works much the same as my old SqlContext  base class using SqlClient: SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc.

Comment: This answer will not build in your code. Its a lazy 'copy and paste' job. You will have to do much work to get the code to work.

Comment: So, totally: 
1. that post is JUST an example - same code works both System.Data.SqlClient imported from EF assembly or directly. 
2. In that particular post example the class copied from source without proof-reading and its absolutely awful for some reason and can't be compiled. BUT next post from @Mr Pumpkin contains corrected version, thanks him for that! The only little addition: if you start completely from the scratch you need to add few namespaces: 
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for an ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 project tested in Visual Studio 2019 community edition.

Create a small database in SQL Express.

Then add a few lines to *appsettings.json* for the connection strings:

```json
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //PROD on some server
    "ProdConnection": "Server=somePRODServerofYours;Database=DB_xxxxx_itemsubdb;User Id=DB_xxxxx_user;Password=xxsomepwdxx;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;encrypt=true",

    //DEV on localhost
    "DevConnection": "Server=someDEVServerofYours;Database=DB_xxxxx_itemsubdb;User Id=DB_xxxxx_user;Password=xxsomepwdxx;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
```

Then use code similar to the following in your controller ....

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SomeNameSpace.Controllers
{
    //This Model class should be saved somewhere else in your project.
    //It is placed here for simplicity.
    public class XtraSimpleContent
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string References { get; set; }
        public string CreatedTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class CodeNotesController : Controller
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public string connStr = String.Empty;

        public CodeNotesController(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");
            }
            else
            {
                connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdConnection");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CodeActionMethodToConnectToSQLnetCore()
        {
            //add  using System.Data.SqlClient;
            //     using System.Data;
            //Along with the using statements, you need the system assembly reference.
            //To add assembly you can do the following.
            //   install nuget package. Right Click on Project > Manage Nuget Packages > 
            //   Search & install 'System.Data.SqlClient' and make sure it is compatible with the type of project (Core/Standard);

            List<XtraSimpleContent> aListOfItems = new List<XtraSimpleContent>();

            string commandText = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ItemSubmissions] 
                                        WHERE SUBMITTEREMAIL = @SUBMITTEREMAIL 
                                        ORDER BY CreationDatetime DESC";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();   //vs  connection.Open();
                using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection, tran))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            command.Parameters.Add("@SUBMITTEREMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                            command.Parameters["@SUBMITTEREMAIL"].Value = "me@someDomain.org";

                            SqlDataReader rdr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();  // vs also alternatives, command.ExecuteReader();  or await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                var itemContent = new XtraSimpleContent();
                                itemContent.UserName = rdr["RCD_SUBMITTERNAME"].ToString();
                                itemContent.References = rdr["RCD_REFERENCES"].ToString();
                                itemContent.CreatedTime = rdr["CreationDatetime"].ToString();

                                aListOfItems.Add(itemContent);
                            }
                        await rdr.CloseAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception Ex)
                        {
                            await connection.CloseAsync()
                            string msg = Ex.Message.ToString();
                            tran.Rollback();
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            string totalinfo = string.Empty;
            foreach (var itm in aListOfItems)
            {
                totalinfo = totalinfo + itm.UserName + itm.References + itm.CreatedTime;
            }
            return Content(totalinfo);

        }
    }
}
```

Test it with something like:

`https://localhost:44302/CodeNotes/CodeActionMethodToConnectToSQLnetCore`

Answer (score 1):

With **UkrGuru.SqlJson** package

**appsettings.json:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "SqlJsonConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=SqlJsonDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSqlJson(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlJsonConnection"));
```

**DbController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DbController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly string _prefix = "api.";

    private readonly DbService _db;
    public DbController(DbService db) => _db = db;

    [HttpGet("{proc}")]
    public async Task<string> Get(string proc, string data = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _db.FromProcAsync($"{_prefix}{proc}", data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("{proc}")]
    public async Task<dynamic> Post(string proc, [FromBody] dynamic data = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return await _db.FromProcAsync<dynamic>($"{_prefix}{proc}",
                (object)data == null ? null : data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```